# Set primary site

Tags: craft3, multi-site

I have a multi-site setup and toggled the primary site inside settings -> sites to "off". So now I don't have any primary site anymore and I get an error preventing me from accessing my admin page saying: "craft\errors\SiteNotFoundException: No primary site exists in xyz". How can I redefine a primary site?

Answer (score 1):

Try to change the `primary` field, from `0` to `1`, in the `craft_sites` DB table.

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't directly solve the OP's issue, but related:

```php
$site = Craft::$app->sites->getSiteByHandle('mySite');
$site->primary = true;
Craft::$app->sites->saveSite($site);
```